# Import JPEG and PDF at same size/scale

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I'm using this script to import both PDF's and JPEG's into a single PDF. It runs fine and works as it should, Except: the images do not appear at the same scale/size as the PDF's.

Images (all landscape) run the range from 1280 x 960 to 4912 x 3264, and I cannot control the sizes. The script does an AddPage() for a single image at the top of the PDF.

In the final output the JPEG's appear at about 50% of the size of the PDF's. How do I get them to scale at the same size, whether to the screen output or a file output?

```
$GLOBALS['txt'] = 'Cover Text';
$GLOBALS['mid_x'] = 11/2;

// iterate through the files
    $files = glob('pdfs/*.{pdf,PDF}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $imagefiles = glob('pdfs/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG}', GLOB_BRACE);   

require('fpdf17/fpdf.php');
require('fpdi/fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI("L","in","Letter");
$pdf->SetMargins(.1,.1,.1);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('newimages/03-March-2013.jpg', 0, 0, 11, 8.5, "JPG");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',48);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255); // White
// Centering a cell with unknown text length
$pdf->Text($GLOBALS['mid_x']-$pdf->GetStringWidth($GLOBALS['txt'])/2,7,$GLOBALS['txt']);
$im = 0;
$pageNo = 0;
foreach ($files AS $filename) {
// get the page count
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($filename);
// iterate through all pages
$pdf->AddPage('L', array("11", "8.5"));
$pdf->Image('newimages/' . basename($imagefiles[$im]), 0, 0, 11, 8.5, "JPG");
$pdf->Text(1.5,7,basename($imagefiles[$im]));
for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    // import a page
    $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    // get the size of the imported page
    $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);
    // create a page (landscape or portrait depending on the imported page size)
    if ($size['w'] > $size['h']) {
        $pdf->AddPage('L', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
    } else {
        //$pdf->AddPage('P', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
    }
    // use the imported page
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateId); 
    }
    $im = ($im + 1);
    }
// Output the new PDF
$pdf->Output();
```